# Fastest way to check if value is in array many times

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of some values between `-15` and `31` and I have to check, if some `x` is in this array for `~300 000 000` times. Because there is negative values, I can't create boolean array. Now I am creating `HashSet` from original array and use `.contains()` method, but this is too slow.  Is there any faster way or trick?

**Update** I create this array from another one (so I can use any structure I want)

Comment: If the negative numbers are the only thing preventing you from using a boolean array: use an offset: `int offset = 15; if( myBoolean[ x - offset ] ) { /* .. */ }`.

Comment: Did you create the array? How about using a binary search tree instead of an array?

Comment: How are you getting the array? Do you declare/instantiate it? Are you reading it from file?

Comment: @Sirko: Exactly the solution I was writing up :)

Comment: I assume that somewhere you are either creating it, adding value one by one, or reading from file. I would then create an index counter for faster reads.

Comment: @leigero: with array you can check in constant time (and very little, in fact), with binary tree you need at least O(log n).

Comment: Is the array sorted like e.g. in ascending order? You can try a binary search.

Comment: @ffriend Good call. I was thinking 300 million values between the ranges, not 300 million comparisons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could easily create a `boolean` array and just offset the index:

```
// Do this once...
int minValueInclusive = -15;
int maxValueExclusive = 31;
boolean[] presence = new boolean[maxValueExclusive - minValueInclusive + 1];
for (int value : array) {
    presence[value - minValueInclusive] = true;
}
```

Then to check for presence:

```
if (presence[index - minValueInclusive]) {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, as you're using fewer than 64 bits you could store the whole thing in a single `long`, and use bitshifting.

```
// Do this once...
int minValueInclusive = -15;
long presence = 0;
for (int value : array) {
    presence |= 1L << (value - minValueInclusive);
}
```

Then to check for presence:

```
if ((presence & (1L << (index - minValueInclusive))) != 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @JohnDow: See my updated answer for a version which is probably even faster.

Comment: Long way speeds up the program a little bit. Thank you